# Selecting Multiple Probabilities Column in Range Of .95 to.40

Tags: python, pandas, filter, multiple-columns

Sorry if it sounds too simple, I am a newbie to python. I have a data frame with probabilities for customers (columns) and days (rows)

```
      1990         1991     1992        1993        1994          1995        1996        1997       1998       1999
T                                       
1.0 0.978075    0.983836    0.935958    0.945885    0.949607    0.997269    0.988535    0.951836    0.953030    0.788105
2.0 0.968136    0.976477    0.907848    0.921947    0.927251    0.996013    0.983297    0.930433    0.932138    0.706214
3.0 0.961416    0.971490    0.889165    0.905972    0.912310    0.995157    0.979741    0.916115    0.918155    0.655308
4.0 0.956860    0.968104    0.876644    0.895236    0.902257    0.994574    0.977323    0.906476    0.908738    0.622709
5.0 0.953432    0.965554    0.867303    0.887210    0.894737    0.994134    0.975500    0.899262    0.901689    0.599165
6.0 0.950307    0.963226    0.858843    0.879930    0.887912    0.993731    0.973836    0.892712    0.895288    0.578402
7.0 0.946586    0.960452    0.848843    0.871310    0.879824    0.993250    0.971851    0.884948    0.887698    0.554536
8.0 0.943850    0.958411    0.841538    0.865002    0.873903    0.992896    0.970388    0.879262    0.882139    0.537557
9.0 0.941322    0.956523    0.834828    0.859201    0.868455    0.992567    0.969036    0.874028    0.877020    0.522294


10.0    0.938503    0.954417    0.827385    0.852757    0.862400    0.992200    0.967525    0.868210    0.871330    0.505735
11.0    0.935750    0.952358    0.820161    0.846494    0.856511    0.991841    0.966048    0.862549    0.865793    0.490026
12.0    0.933141    0.950405    0.813354    0.840584    0.850952    0.991499    0.964646    0.857204    0.860564    0.475550
13.0    0.930858    0.948695    0.807425    0.835431    0.846103    0.991199    0.963417    0.852540    0.855999    0.463197
14.0    0.929073    0.947358    0.802812    0.831417    0.842324    0.990965    0.962456    0.848905    0.852442    0.453746
15.0    0.927366    0.946078    0.798416    0.827588    0.838718    0.990740    0.961535    0.845435    0.849046    0.444869
16.0    0.925786    0.944893    0.794362    0.824054    0.835389    0.990531    0.960683    0.842231    0.845910    0.436796
17.0    0.924440    0.943883    0.790920    0.821052    0.832560    0.990354    0.959956    0.839508    0.843244    0.430024
18.0    0.923308    0.943033    0.788032    0.818531    0.830184    0.990204    0.959345    0.837221    0.841006    0.424403
19.0    0.922105    0.942130    0.784970    0.815857    0.827663    0.990045    0.958694    0.834794    0.838629    0.418500
20.0    0.921186    0.941439    0.782637    0.813818    0.825740    0.989923    0.958197    0.832942    0.836816    0.414041
```

I want to filter only columns where I have probabilities to less than .95 to.40. I want to keep only those columns which meet the range (i.e. I want to keep the record number of columns meeting the requirement).

I tried filter

```
df_2 = df[(df <= .95) & (df >= .4)]
```

For example, I should get columns 1992 1994 not 1990 or 1991 and so forth. However, I get lots of NaNs or with some other options, I only get back filtered rows meeting condition. However, I want to keep only the columns where I can get the range of probabilities for all 20 rows.

I would appreciate if someone can help/suggest something to get

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just one line of code is not enough to help. What is in `df`? and in `df_2`? please post more code. Others might follow after you have solved your issue. Also, what does "customers (columns)" mean? From the looks they seem years? Should they meet the range totally or partially? Also, your title is quite specific about a more general problem, which will not help for others to stumble on your question whenever they have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to index on columns where all values are within the range.

Note that `df[(df <= .95) & (df >= .4)]`, will produce a dataframe of `True`/`False`. You cannot index directly a pandas dataframe with another. Indexing will work either on rows or on columns. So you need to reduce to a single dimension with `all`, which will be `True` where all rows satisfy the condition, or `False` otherwise:

```
df.loc[:,(df.gt(0.4) & df.lt(0.95)).all(0)]

      1992      1993      1994      1999
1.0  0.935958  0.945885  0.949607  0.788105
2.0  0.907848  0.921947  0.927251  0.706214
3.0  0.889165  0.905972  0.912310  0.655308
4.0  0.876644  0.895236  0.902257  0.622709
5.0  0.867303  0.887210  0.894737  0.599165
6.0  0.858843  0.879930  0.887912  0.578402
7.0  0.848843  0.871310  0.879824  0.554536
8.0  0.841538  0.865002  0.873903  0.537557
9.0  0.834828  0.859201  0.868455  0.522294
```

---

For the sample input -

```
print(df)

       1990      1991      1992      1993      1994      1995      1996  \
1.0  0.978075  0.983836  0.935958  0.945885  0.949607  0.997269  0.988535   
2.0  0.968136  0.976477  0.907848  0.921947  0.927251  0.996013  0.983297   
3.0  0.961416  0.971490  0.889165  0.905972  0.912310  0.995157  0.979741   
4.0  0.956860  0.968104  0.876644  0.895236  0.902257  0.994574  0.977323   
5.0  0.953432  0.965554  0.867303  0.887210  0.894737  0.994134  0.975500   
6.0  0.950307  0.963226  0.858843  0.879930  0.887912  0.993731  0.973836   
7.0  0.946586  0.960452  0.848843  0.871310  0.879824  0.993250  0.971851   
8.0  0.943850  0.958411  0.841538  0.865002  0.873903  0.992896  0.970388   
9.0  0.941322  0.956523  0.834828  0.859201  0.868455  0.992567  0.969036   

         1997      1998      1999  
1.0  0.951836  0.953030  0.788105  
2.0  0.930433  0.932138  0.706214  
3.0  0.916115  0.918155  0.655308  
4.0  0.906476  0.908738  0.622709  
5.0  0.899262  0.901689  0.599165  
6.0  0.892712  0.895288  0.578402  
7.0  0.884948  0.887698  0.554536  
8.0  0.879262  0.882139  0.537557  
9.0  0.874028  0.877020  0.522294
```

Comment: Little explanation, very unlikely to help others. Maybe you could explain why his approach does not work, and why yours does at least.

Comment: I don't think there'll be many people searching for `Selecting Multiple Probabilities Column in Range Of .95 to.40` This is likely a dupe, can't find it. Adding a few more explanations though... @MikeMajara